# Call options for webdriver in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to open a website and accept the cookie button via a bot. The problem is that the website does not open maximized automatically, so I entered the options to maximize it. However, i don't know how to call the options in my code without getting an error message. In my code below, how and where would I add the options calling?

````
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com
driver.get(url)

button = driver.find_element_by_name('agree')
button.click()```


Thanks for your help!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com"
driver.get(url)
```